# En la base de datos SQL este script devuelve la fecha en un año desconocido '1986 cuando lo que quiero que devuelva es ''2020-03-01'

Tags: sql-server, date, cast

```
DECLARE @F DATE

SET @F = '31/03/2020'

SELECT CAST (@F AS VARCHAR)  AS F
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sabias que las mayusculas se considera gritar? y ademas, tu pregunta no dice nada de nada...

Comment: suena a que el formato que escribes sea incorrecto... has probado a poner el valor como '2020/03/31' o '2020-03-31'

Answer (score 1):

El formato de fecha estándar de SQL Server es: YYYY-MM-DD.

La variable @F debes asignarla así:

```
SET @F = '2020-03-31';
```

Si quieres asignarla en formato DD/MM/YYYY, debes usar dateformat así:

```
set dateformat dmy;

set @F = '31/03/2020';
```